# How to scroll UITableView to specific position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

How can I scroll the table's cell to specific position ? I have a table which shows 3 rows (according to height). what I want is if I click on 1st row than according to table's height the 1st row should scroll and get new position (center) and same for other rows. I tried contenOffset but did not work..

EDITED :

In short some thing like data picker when we select any row in picker the row scrolls to the center.

Thanks..

Comment: If I scroll down to the tenth item in the list and my display is showing item 10, 11, 12.  Are you saying if I click the first row (which is item 10) to center item 10 on the screen effectively displaying item 9, 10, 11?

Comment: ya... similar to the data picker...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

finally I found... it will work nice when table displays only 3 rows... if rows are more change should be accordingly...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{    
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{  
    return 30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {         
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello roe no. %d",[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * theCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView     
                                              cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGPoint tableViewCenter = [tableView contentOffset];
    tableViewCenter.y += myTable.frame.size.height/2;

    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,theCell.center.y-65) animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadData]; 
 }
```

Comment: Just a comment - hardcoding values into code is bad practice. Here I see you put  [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,theCell.center.y-65) animated:YES]; - the -65 is bad. Consider using code for 65 like theCell.frame.size.height for example.

Comment: @Rocotilos yes I agree. But I have clearly mentioned that "it will work nice when table displays only 3 rows... if rows are more change should be accordingly... " It was just an example code. Also I have used this table as UIPicker.

Comment: It's not working, beside there is better solution than that.

Comment: we can use a counter value to store the number of row we want to display and if we want to display more row we should change the counter value

Answer (score 141):

it should work using `- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated` using it this way:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                             animated:YES];
```

`atScrollPosition` could take any of these values:

```
typedef enum {
UITableViewScrollPositionNone,
UITableViewScrollPositionTop,
UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle,
UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
} UITableViewScrollPosition;
```

Comment: will this method call when I select the row ?

Comment: No, it will select a row when it gets called. It will NOT get called when you select a row. There is a subtle difference.

Comment: I want table to scroll when I select the row... how can I set the cell's contentOffset according to the current table's height ?

Comment: When you select a row, the method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in `UITableViewDelegate` gets called, so place a call to the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` in that method. I strongly suggest you to read the `Table View Programming Guide for iOS` as well as the `UITableView`reference and `UITableViewDelegate` reference, you will find them very useful, and after all, that is what documentation is for

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 4.2 version:**

```
let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
```

**Enum:** These are the available tableView scroll positions - here for reference. You don't need to include this section in your code.

```
public enum UITableViewScrollPosition : Int {

case None
case Top
case Middle
case Bottom
}
```

**DidSelectRow:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let theCell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if let theCell = theCell {
        var tableViewCenter:CGPoint = tableView.contentOffset
        tableViewCenter.y += tableView.frame.size.height/2

        tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, theCell.center.y-65)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
[tableview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

This will take your tableview to the first row.

Comment: @Parveen Thanks it helps me alot

Comment: Answer for xamarin developers: tblRecord.ScrollRectToVisible(CoreGraphics.CGRect.FromLTRB(0, 0, 1, 1), true);

Answer (score 15):

Use `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:scrollPosition animated:YES];` 
Scrolls the receiver until a row identified by index path is at a particular location on the screen.

And

```
scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:
```

Scrolls the table view so that the selected row nearest to a specified position in the table view is at that position.

Comment: and how can I calculate the height of table ? means do I have to calculate the height of table with all rows or just visible rows ?

Comment: or say , how can I set the cell's contentOffset according to the current table's height ? do I need to calculate the table's height with all rows or just visible rows ?

Comment: if its standard table cell its height will be 44.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that if you use the `setContentOffset` approach, it may cause your table view/collection view to jump a little. I would honestly try to go about this another way. A recommendation is to use the scroll view delegate methods you are given for free.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply single line of code:**

```
self.tblViewMessages.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: arrayChat.count-1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: isAnimeted)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, your table view only has one row and one section, you also can use following approach

```
 challengeInfoTableView.scrollRectToVisible(challengeInfoCell.challengeDescriptionTextView!.frame, animated: false)
```

In this case, you can directly scroll to the correct text field, text view, label etc.