# Why isn't MvxStandardTableViewSource SelectedItem updating properly?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind a `UITableView` to an `ObservableCollection<MyTypeViewModel>` using `MvxStandardTableViewSource`, and I'm getting weird behavior and bindings that aren't working

The (partial) code is this:

```
tblFeatures = new UITableView ();
mSource = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(tblFeatures, "TitleText Name");

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyTypeView, MyTypeViewModel> ();

set.Bind(mSource).To (vm => vm.Objects);
set.Bind(mSource).For(s => s.SelectedItem).To (vm => vm.SelectedObject);

set.Apply ();
```

What I'm seeing is that when I select an item in the **table**, it does update `SelectedObject` with the new value.  But when I change `SelectedObject` by some other means, the table **does not** update the displayed selected item.  I have verified that the `SelectedObject` really is being changed, by setting a breakpoint and by binding another control to it; the other control (a label) does change as the selection changes, but the `UITableView` does not.

Am I doing something wrong, or could this be an issue in MVVMCross?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selecteditem binding was requested as a 'nice to have' and was mainly requested for the user story where a user clicks on a list item - so this is currently a 'one way to source' implementation.

The very basic details and some code can be found via - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/278

In truth, the current binding is abusing the 'selected' paradigm - as it doesn't really reflect the selection state of the cell and also has no handling of mutiselect - instead it just lets the viewmodel know the latest tapped item.

If there are genuine user stories/requirements for full two'way binding, then these should be addable - eg if the user story were for scrolling the item into view then 'scrollToRowAt' could be used - see [How to scroll UITableView to specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856427/how-to-scroll-uitableview-to-specific-position) - but this again might not be true 'selection' within the uitableview.

if you wanted to implement this yourself it should be fairly straight-forward to override the binding with your own one (see the custom binding n+1 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com for an intro on custom bindings).

> could this be an issue in MVVMCross?

Overall I think I'd categorise it as a known limitation of that particular binding caused by lack of user demand and by some confusion over whether selection genuinely means selection in the touch screen era.

if it was logged as a bug I'd say it wasn't.. If it was logged ss a feature request I'd try getting as much user input as i could about what devs really want from this, whether they want true cell selection or scroll into view, both or something more.

Comment: Thanks as always for the detailed and thoughtful answer.  Armed with this, I hacked together what I needed by observing the property change on the view model and selecting the row in the table manually.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. So selecting really did mean selecting for you? (i.e. with highlighting and row selection?) - if you've got genuine user requirements here then I'd be very happy for you to comment on that issue in github or to open a new feature request. Real user requirements are gold dust :)

Comment: I did need simple selection, yes.  This seems like a reasonable candidate for the default behavior.  I'm not sure about scroll-into-view, but perhaps that could be a property of MvxSimpleTableViewSource (or a suitable base class), defaulting to false.  I'm also not sure about multi-select; I didn't need it in my case, but I guess that should be supported as well.  I'll add this on github too.

Comment: I accomplished what I needed by watching the view model, but I think it would be cleaner to accomplish this by overriding the SelectedItem binding, i.e. somehow telling MvxStandardTableViewSource to use my custom routine when the selected item changes.  But I can't figure out how to do that.  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

By other means you mean not from UI thread I presume.  Please try by invoking the change on UI thread.