# TableView Scroll Back To Same Position

Tags: uitableview

I have a tableview controller with over 50 cells, and when you select one of the cells to view the details of it and then tap the back button to go to the complete list of cells, it doesn't scroll back to the same position as you chose the cell.

How could I fix this problem and make it to where when you select lets say cell 50, when going back to the main tableview it shows cell 50 rather the top of the tableview.

Thanks!

Comment: what have you implemented in the `viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: Please refer below links: it may help you. 1>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856427/how-to-scroll-uitableview-to-specific-position  2>http://make-smart-iphone-apps.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-maintain-uitableview-scrolled.html

Comment: I do not have a viewWillAppear method.