# UITableview scroll to the particular index , that cell to be on the top as first index?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios11

I have an `array` of data with past and future events. when page load time the tableview scroll to the  first future events. scroll down time shows the past events

```c
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    if ([arryIndex count]!=0) {
        NSNumber * indexPathData = [arryIndex objectAtIndex:index];
        int number = [indexPathData intValue];
        [tableEvents setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, tableEvents.contentSize.height - tableEvents.bounds.size.height)animated:YES];
        [tableEvents scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:number inSection:0]atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail

Answer (score 0):

check answer in this Link [How to scroll UITableView to specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856427/how-to-scroll-uitableview-to-specific-position)

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:YourIndex inSection:0];
[YourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                 atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle 
                         animated:YES];
```

Comment: Scrolling is working. but is not comes up. i changed the height of table then its working fine